# RecyclerView showing nothing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app that, in theory, have to load images from my internal storage an showing it up on a RecyclerView. I think I followed all the steps correctly and after many unsuccessful tries I'm asking here. So I think the code to catch up the data to the adapter is wrong, but I cannot think of anything to verify that. Any help, Observation, suggestions are greatly appreciated. These are my files:

Photos.java (Where I get the data):

```
public class Photos {
static ArrayList<String> filenameListTemp=new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<File> photosList=new ArrayList<>();

public static ArrayList<String> getPhotos(File internal){
    File listFolers[]=internal.listFiles();
    if (listFolers!=null && listFolers.length>0){
        for (File file:listFolers) {
            if (file.isDirectory()){
                getPhotos(file);
            }
            else {
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".png")||file.getName().endsWith(".jpg")||file.getName().endsWith(".gif")||file.getName().endsWith(".bmp")){
                    String temp =file.getPath().substring(0,file.getPath().lastIndexOf('/'));

                    if (!filenameListTemp.contains(temp)){
                        filenameListTemp.add(temp); //This add names
                        photosList.add(file);// This add Files
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        return filenameListTemp;
    }
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<String> photos=new ArrayList<>();
LayoutInflater layoutinflater;



public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> photos) {
    this.context=context;
    this.photos=photos;
    layoutinflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}



@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_list,parent,false);
    RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder=new RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photos.get(position)));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return photos.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
   }
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
File expath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    adapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, Photos.getPhotos(expath));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you log your data if you are able to load from the internal storage? Because not getting any data displayed in  your recyclerview could mean that there is no data source available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Make sure you have added permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` to read external storage.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**2.** Put some `logs` in `getPhotos()` method, to check the size of `filenameListTemp` and `photosList` to know weather its working or not.

Comment: Thanks!!, I made that, and result was the arraylist passed to the adapter was empty. And I've forgotten to add runtime permissions

Comment: My pleasure.... If my answer seems useful please give an upvote. FYI, I have already upvoted your question to help you to get the privilege for upvote. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the arraylist you're passing in adapter have size greater then 0. If the size is 0 then it will show anything in adapter

Thanks!!

Comment: Yup, It was that, the arraylist was empty after all. I got it working now